# correct use of linux inotify - reopen every time?

Tags: linux, redhat, inotify

I'm debugging a system load problem that a customer encounters on their production system and they've made a test application that simulates the load to reproduce the problem:

[image: sexy graph]

In this particular workload, one of the things the coder did was to:

```
while(1)
  initialize inotify
  watch a directory for events
  receive event
  process event
  remove watch
  close inotify fd
```

Strangely enough, the high system load comes from the `close()` of the inotify fd:

```
inotify_init()                          = 4 <0.000020>
inotify_add_watch(4, "/mnt/tmp/msys_sim/QUEUES/Child_032", IN_CREATE) = 1 <0.059537>
write(1, "Child [032] sleeping\n", 21)  = 21 <0.000012>
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0SrcFile.b8tlfT\0\0", 512) = 32 <0.231012>
inotify_rm_watch(4, 1)                  = 0 <0.000044>
close(4)                                = 0 <0.702530>
open("/mnt/tmp/msys_sim/QUEUES/Child_032", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4 <0.000031>
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0 <0.000010>
getdents(4, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 88 <0.000048>
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0 <0.000009>
write(1, "Child [032] dequeue [SrcFile.b8t"..., 37) = 37 <0.000011>
unlink("/mnt/tmp/msys_sim/QUEUES/Child_032/SrcFile.b8tlfT") = 0 <0.059298>
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0 <0.000011>
getdents(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48 <0.000038>
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0 <0.000009>
close(4)                                = 0 <0.000012>
inotify_init()                          = 4 <0.000020>
inotify_add_watch(4, "/mnt/tmp/msys_sim/QUEUES/Child_032", IN_CREATE) = 1 <0.040385>
write(1, "Child [032] sleeping\n", 21)  = 21 <0.000903>
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0SrcFile.mQgUSh\0\0", 512) = 32 <0.023423>
inotify_rm_watch(4, 1)                  = 0 <0.000012>
close(4)                                = 0 <0.528736>
```

What could possibly be causing the close() call to take such an enormous amount of time? I can identify two possible things:

- closing and reinitializing inotify *every* time
- There are 256K files (flat) in `/mnt/tmp/msys_sim/SOURCES` and a particular file in `/mnt/tmp/msys_sim/QUEUES/Child_032` is hardlinked to one in that directory. But SOURCES is never opened by the above process

Is it an artifact of using inotify wrong? What can I point at to say "What you're doing is WRONG!"?

---

Output of `perf top` (I had been looking for this!)

```
Events: 109K cycles
 70.01%  [kernel]      [k] _spin_lock
 24.30%  [kernel]      [k] __fsnotify_update_child_dentry_flags
  2.24%  [kernel]      [k] _spin_unlock_irqrestore
  0.64%  [kernel]      [k] __do_softirq
  0.60%  [kernel]      [k] __rcu_process_callbacks
  0.46%  [kernel]      [k] run_timer_softirq
  0.40%  [kernel]      [k] rcu_process_gp_end
```

Sweet! I suspect a spinlock somewhere and the *entire system* goes highly latent when this happens.

Comment: how often an inotify event happens?

Comment: You may find it beneficial to run `perf top` to see what the kernel is really busy doing.

Comment: By random looking into source files I found `fsnotify_flush_notify` that's used for "Called when a group is being torn down to clean up any outstanding event notifications" that seems to be iterating over every unprocessed event to do something with it. Maybe if there is lot of events happening, before you process the first event, it has to tear down whole bunch of them before processing next one. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the pseudo code `inotify` loop would look like this:

```
initialize inotify
watch a directory | file for events

while(receive event) {
  process event
}

[ remove watch ]
close inotify fd
```

**There is no need to remove the watch and reinitialize inotify on every loop.**

Comment: inotify depends on the inode. If the directory was deleted and recreted, I expect you would need to recreate the inotify.

Comment: yeah, that's true. It depends on the inode. However thats a special case and even this would not require to reinitialize inotify

Comment: Is there any documentation I can point at to say that it is improper to reinitialize on every loop?

Comment: why it should? It is just a file descriptor. Would you close and reopen a file descriptor after each read?

Comment: I completely agree! I'm just looking for documentation that says "You should use inotify this way".

Comment: @MikeyB Yeah I did research in order to find something like this for you, but didn't found anything. The only "official" documentation is in kernel sources: `Documentation/filesystems/inotify.txt`

Comment: You may have a look at the source code of programs that use inotify, like tail (on Linux). However, this isn't an official documentation of course. You need to trust me :) (I wrote a PHP library around inotify and that's why had a deeper look into inotify)

Comment: Hi, Just a small query, while code is in the "process event" part in your example and a new file is created in the watching directory, what happens? Please answer this OP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816535/using-inotify-on-a-busy-directory

Comment: Between closing and re-opening the inotify stream, there is a small window where you loose all events happening in the according directory, so you have a race condition there. If you have additional code that checks the directory's state which is required on first run, this may reduce the window even further. Still, re-opening is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to duplicate your problem. I dont get the same results you see.
But yes, its wrong to use inotify like that. Normally you initialize inotify then read / poll from its watch descriptor.

I ran this with `strace -T` and get nowhere near that level of performance on `close()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define WATCHDIR "./watched"

void child_run(void)
{
    printf("Child spawned..\n");
    int fd;
    if (chdir(WATCHDIR))
        err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot chdir in child");

    /* Care not if this fails.. */
    unlink("myfile.dat");

    while (1) {
        fd = open("myfile.dat", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        if (fd < 0) {
            warn("Cannot create necessary file.. sleeping");
            sleep(1);
        }
        close(fd);
        fd = -1;
        if (unlink("myfile.dat") < 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot unlink file in watched directory");
    }

}

int main() 
{
    int watch_fd = -1;
    int watched = -1;
    struct inotify_event ev[128];
    memset(ev, 0, sizeof(&ev)*128);

    if (mkdir(WATCHDIR, S_IRWXU) < 0) {
        if (errno != EEXIST) {
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot create directory");
        }
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        child_run();
        exit(0);
    }

    while (1) {
        if ((watch_fd = inotify_init1(IN_CLOEXEC)) < 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot init inotify");

        if (watch_fd < 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot init watch");

        if ((watched = inotify_add_watch(watch_fd, WATCHDIR, IN_CREATE)) < 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot add watched directory");

        if (read(watch_fd, ev, sizeof(ev)*128) < 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot read from watcher");

        if (inotify_rm_watch(watch_fd, watched) < 0)
            err(EX_OSERR, "Cannot remove watch");

        close(watch_fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this do you get the same performance on that host?

Comment: Not initially, but this is building up over *days* (see the graph)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the smoking gun. From profiling the kernel ([perf top is what I was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554806/correct-use-of-linux-inotify-reopen-every-time?noredirect=1#comment30740780_20554806)):

```
Events: 109K cycles
 70.01%  [kernel]      [k] _spin_lock
 24.30%  [kernel]      [k] __fsnotify_update_child_dentry_flags
  2.24%  [kernel]      [k] _spin_unlock_irqrestore
  0.64%  [kernel]      [k] __do_softirq
  0.60%  [kernel]      [k] __rcu_process_callbacks
  0.46%  [kernel]      [k] run_timer_softirq
  0.40%  [kernel]      [k] rcu_process_gp_end
```

Spending 70% of our time in _spin_lock (remember, we theorized this may be the cause) explains all the symptoms. The second entry on the list is likely the culprit:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/notify/fsnotify.c?a=sh#L52

Without thoroughly analyzing the code, it appears that with the test case provided, that code is going to loop over all 262K directory entries in SOURCES *inside* a kernel lock. That behaviour is probably incorrect and comes from using the inotify API incorrectly.

Calling a fs remount (with the test still running) makes it behave better:

```
Events: 38K cycles                                                                                                          
 20.41%  [kernel]      [k] _spin_lock
 17.43%  [kernel]      [k] _spin_unlock_irqrestore
 12.40%  [kernel]      [k] __fsnotify_update_child_dentry_flags
  6.44%  [kernel]      [k] run_timer_softirq
  5.65%  [kernel]      [k] __do_softirq          
  5.18%  [kernel]      [k] update_shares
  5.02%  [kernel]      [k] __rcu_process_callbacks
```

But still not ideal.