# Using inotify on a busy directory

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I am using `inotify` on a busy directory(files keep on getting generated). I wish to catch the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events for all of them.

So I tried something like this.

```
fd = inotify_init();
inotify_add_watch(fd, DIR_PATH, IN_CLOSE_WRITE);
while(1) {
    len = read(fd, buff, INOTIFY_EVENT_SIZE);
    if (len < 0) {
        PRINT_ERROR("Read failed. Keep watching.\n");
        continue;
    }
    /* Process the event */
}
```

This method is failing to catch the events that are generated while I am processing the event of first read. I expected it to work though.

How should I handle this? Please let me know in case you see something missing.

Comment: How is it failing exactly? Which events are not caught? How did you notice that?

Comment: The events will getting queued, until a limit. The limit can be set in `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I was waiting on IN_CLOSE_WRITE, But the files in my dir were actually moved from a diff place. SO the event was not getting caught. I changed the event name and it worked well.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you. Yes they are getting queued. By adding mask IN_MOVE it worked well for me as the files were actually moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was waiting on IN_CLOSE_WRITE, But the files in my dir were actually moved from a diff place. SO the event was not getting caught. I changed the event mast to IN_MOVE and it worked well.